# How is High Precision in Op-amps based in BJT accomplished?

Tags: bjt

With BJTs there is always an associated Vbe. So when designing with them and taking output from emitter, I simply add a tiny offset so the signal lower than Vbe won't be clipped below ground, then clamp to ground any excess offsetting. I also employ few simple rules together with this so that I encounter fewer Vbe and Vce's. But sometimes I just can't avoid them without making the implementation messy or costly.

Since there have High Precision Op-amps out there (I'm sure some are BJT based), are there any techniques used by Microelectronic Engineers that can more cleanly mitigate these forward voltage drops?

EDIT:

To be specific, I need to balance 2 sides of a circuit. I've settled on raising the effective ground of the other side, but I can't design a simple voltage follower (that will be the effective ground) that is accurate enough and does not disturb the opposite side.

Comment: Forward drops (Vbe) are not a problem per se - you simply take them into account in any design along with the linear and non-linear characteristics of the device, temperature variation etc. The general tools of op amp design include long tail pairs, constant current sources, current mirrors and so on - take a look at http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee140/sp11/labs/Lab2.ee140.s11.v1.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The solution to DC accuracy revolves around the differential input amplifier: -

[image]

In a nutshell the forward volt drops across each base-emitter junction cancel out and what is amplified is the difference between Vin+ and Vin- with no offset.

Bottom line is that only in exceptional cases will the discreet version be used; almost every application of this type is served by the ubiquitous op-amp.

Comment: About the bottom line.... Funny, as I've been using it as a comparator. Not that accurate (so I do amplify the input), but works when at least one of the input is DC. So ironically, in the scenario that I avoid to use it is what you guys have been using it for.

Comment: I have to add, it is an incomplete comparator. Only outputting whether the AC is less than (HI) or greater than the DC (LO). Also, the LO is not quite VEE, but mid-level of VEE and VCC. You do have to increase the collector  and decrease the emitter resistors.

Comment: And I have to say I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @Majin_Boo if you are happy with this answer please consider formally accepting it.